# What is the difference between Struts 2.3.x and Struts 2.5.x

Tags: java, struts2

I know the difference between Struts 1 and 2.

But what I don't know and cannot find an answer to, is why there are two versions of Struts 2?

Edit 1: As per this announcement https://struts.apache.org/announce-2019#a20190912 on Sep 2019, version 2.3.x has reached its EOL and now we only have 2.5.x version

Comment: Although this question is too broad, I really cannot find an answer to it any where. Even on the official site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a release notes document here: https://struts.apache.org/docs/version-notes-25.html. It contains the whole changelog, and it also references the fixed tickets.

The 2.5.x series introduced some breaking changes, so the development is now branching, as 2.3.x is still supported. Basically they backport some changes to 2.3.x without breaking things.

Comment: Thank you. But that really does not answer why the folks @Struts maintain and release 2 versions of Struts.

Comment: Based on your comment, I think it all relates to the point: "Struts2 is now build with JDK7" in the release notes you just referred to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of few changes made/replace/deprecated from Struts 2.3.x and Struts 2.5.x that I found while Googling the internet.

1. StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter -> Inside the `web.xml` filter of Struts 2.5.x has been changed.
2. Document Type Definition -> Struts DTD was updated to 2.5 version.
3. Package Names Changed -> Some classes were moved to different packages.
4. Tags Attributes -> Struts 2.5.x UI tags attribute id was replaced with var attribute.

You can also check [Difference between Struts 2.3.x and 2.5.x](https://www.websparrow.org/struts/difference-between-struts-2-3-x-and-2-5-x) for detail information.